# Probability of a structure of consecutive head tosses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, stochastic-processes

**The exercise:** A group of N friends sits around a table shaped as a regular polygon with N sides, one person on each side. Everyone tosses a fair coin once and a person is called positive if she and the people sitting on adjacent sides obtain heads. What are the expectation and variance of the number of positive people?

**My attempt:** I managed to find the expectation proceeding as follows. Introduce random variables $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_N$ such that: $X_i = 1$ if persons $i-1, \ i, \ i+1$ all obtain heads for $i \in \{2,\ldots, N-1\}$; $X_1 = 1$ if people $N, 1, 2$ all obtain heads; and $X_N = 1$ if people $N-1, N, 1$ all obtain heads; otherwise $X_i = 0$.

Then $Y=X_1 + \ldots + X_N$ is the number of positive people and it remains to find $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ and $\mathbb{Var}(Y)$. By linearity of expectation (the following is reworked as discussed in the comments):

\begin{align}
{
\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(X_1 + \ldots + X_N) = \mathbb{E}(X_1) +\ldots+ \mathbb{E}(X_{N})
}
\end{align}

Now each of the terms above is equal to $\frac{1}{8}$, which yields $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \frac{N}{8}$.

Using $\mathbb{Var}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(Y^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y)^2$, it suffices to find $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y^2) = \mathbb{E}\left((X_1 + \ldots X_N)^2\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) + \sum\limits_{i\neq j}\mathbb{E}(X_i X_j) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N\mathbb{E}(X_i) + \sum\limits_{i \neq j}\mathbb{P}(X_i=X_j=1)
\end{align}

As pointed out in the comments, we break the second term into three scenarios:  $⋅∙∙ \ ⋅, \ ⋅∙⋅∙ \ ⋅$, and $⋅∙⋅⋅∙ \ ⋅$; the last represents the case when $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent.

1. Scenario $⋅∙∙⋅$
   For fixed $i$ and $j$:
   \begin{align}
   \mathbb{P}(X_i=X_j=1) = \mathbb{P}(X_j = 1 \vert X_i = 1)\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{2^4} \ \ \  \text{for} \ \  N \geq 4 \\
   \frac{1}{2^3} \ \ \  \text{for} \ \ N=3
   \end{cases}
   \end{align}
   The summation contains $2N$ such terms.
2. Scenario $⋅∙⋅∙⋅$
   This case only appears for $N \geq 4$. For fixed $i$ and $j$:
   \begin{align}
   \mathbb{P}(X_i=X_j=1) = \mathbb{P}(X_j = 1 \vert X_i = 1)\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{2^5} \ \ \  \text{for} \ \  N \geq 5 \\
   \frac{1}{2^4} \ \ \  \text{for} \ \ N=4 \\
   \end{cases}
   \end{align}
   This scenario occurs in 4 ways for $N=4$ and $2N$ ways for $N\geq 5$.
3. Scenario $⋅∙⋅⋅∙⋅$
   Here the two fixed people $i$ and $j$ are independent. This case occurs only for $N \geq 6$.
   \begin{align}
   \mathbb{P}(X_i=X_j=1) = \mathbb{P}(X_j = 1)\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = 
   \frac{1}{2^6} \ \ \  \text{for} \ \  N \geq 6
   \end{align}
   There are $N(N-5)$ ways to choose this option. This is because there are $N$ choices for the first number and $N-5$ for the second (we need to ignore the chosen number and two numbers on each of its sides).

Summarising,
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i \neq j}\mathbb{P}(X_i=X_j=1) = \begin{cases}
\frac{6}{2^3} = \frac{3}{4} \ \ \  \text{for} \ \  N =3 \\
\frac{4}{2^4}+\frac{8}{2^4} = \frac{3}{4} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N = 4 \\
\frac{10}{2^5}+\frac{10}{2^4} = \frac{15}{16} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N = 5 \\
\frac{N(N-5)}{2^6}+\frac{2N}{2^5} + \frac{2N}{2^4} = \frac{N(N+7)}{64} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N \geq 6
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y^2) = \begin{cases}
\frac{9}{8}\ \ \  \text{for} \ \  N =3 \\
\frac{5}{4} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N = 4 \\
\frac{25}{16} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N = 5 \\
\frac{N(N+15)}{64} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N \geq 6
\end{cases}
\end{align}
resulting in
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Var}(Y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{63}{64}\ \ \  \text{for} \ \  N =3 \\
\frac{64}{64} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N = 4 \\
\frac{75}{64} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N = 5 \\
\frac{15N}{64} \ \ \   \text{for} \ \ N \geq 6
\end{cases}
\end{align}

A simulation confirms both results, the theoretical values are marked with the blue lines (and almost invisible points in the case of variance): 
[image: Mean vs N]
[image: Variance vs N]

**My questions:**
1. Is there a better way to tackle this problem? For example, I tried using a Markov chain approach, but it seemed too complicated. A dream would be to obtain a PGF for the random variable Y.
2. Are there similar, let's call them "dragon eating its tail", famous problems?

Comment: Seen this [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2826986/75923). Have you changed your first name from "ryszard" to "Mateusz" maybe?

Comment: oh, wow, that's my brother, he didn't tell me he posted it, pardon! :)

Comment: Why did you compute $\mathbb{E}(X_1 + X_N)$ the way you did instead of using linearity of expectation to simplify it to $\mathbb{E}(X_1) + \mathbb{E}(X_N)$? Granted, it would change the answer, but I'm reasonably sure the answer you got was wrong. (You wrote $2^3$ where you should have written $2^4$).

Comment: Sanity check: if $N=3$ then the expectation should give $\frac38$ (so not $\frac{N+1}8=\frac48$).The correct expression for expectation is $\frac{N}8$.

Comment: Yes, of course, I got that wrong! It should just be $\frac{N}{8}$ using the linearity of expectation. Thank you DavidK and drhab, I will fix that now.

Comment: Now you can make the same simplification in the calculation of the variance. There's nothing special about the arbitrary place where we decided to let the numbering wrap around from $1$ to $N$. Then you'll just have two types of terms to deal with.

Comment: Cheers, joriki! I have done that and updated the question accordingly. The problem is symmetric, I am not sure what made me think differently

Comment: small simplification: $\mathbb EX_i^2=P(X_i=1)$

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I think that even $3$ types of $X_iX_j$ with $i\neq j$ must be discerned. $\cdot\bullet\bullet\cdot$, $\cdot\bullet\cdot\bullet\cdot$ and $\cdot\bullet\cdot\cdot\bullet\cdot$. In last case there is independence.

Comment: You are right, that was oversight. Nice drawing, by the way!

Comment: @drhab: Well done, good and faithful servant! ;-)